# android store score and save on app

Tags: android, android-intent, int, sharedpreferences

I want to be able to get multiple intents from different activities and store it in on the application state.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int score1 = intent.getIntExtra("comp", 0);

Intent intent2 = getIntent();
int score2 = intent2.getIntExtra("comp2", 0);

int score = score1 + score2;

//setting preferences
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putInt("key", score);
editor.commit();
```

and to get data from `SharedPreferences` I do:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int scoretotal = prefs.getInt("key", 0); //0 is the default value
s1.setText("Score: " + scoretotal);
```

But this only stores the first or second intent, also the value returns to 0 when the application is closed. I want the application to store both values and stay on the app permanently until the app is uninstalled.

Comment: if you want it to store both values, why do you not save both????

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, This is what you need to do when you mean `**multiple intents** from **different activities** and store it in on the application state`!

In **Activity A**,

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int score1 = intent.getIntExtra("comp", 0);
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", 
                            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// Get the 2nd Score from shared preference
int score2= prefs.getInt("comp2", 0); //0 is the default value


 // Sum both the scores so that the value in Activity A is updated:
 int score = score1 + score2;

 // Save score1 and total score in shared preference
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
 editor.putInt("comp", score1 );
 editor.putInt("key", score);
 editor.commit();
```

In **Activity B**,

```
 Intent intent2 = getIntent();
 int score2 = intent2.getIntExtra("comp2", 0);
 SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", 
                            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

 // Get the 1st Score from shared preference
 int score1= prefs.getInt("comp", 0); //0 is the default value

 // Sum both the scores so that the value in Activity B is updated:
 int score = score1 + score2;

 // Save score1 and total score in shared preference
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
 editor.putInt("comp2", score2 );
 editor.putInt("key", score);
 editor.commit();
```

Answer (score -2):

why you are not doing like this? :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    int score1 = intent.getIntExtra("comp", 0);
    int score2 = intent.getIntExtra("comp2", 0);

    int score = score1 + score2;
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("key", score);
    editor.commit();
```

Comment: and what does this have to do with the actual problem?

Comment: the SharedPreferences does not hold the added intents and only holds one of them

Comment: @user3541743 You are adding two integers not two intents.. Check whether you get values on both intents.. SharedPreferences acts like a persistent storage it won't be cleared untill you actually clear it..

Comment: i am adding the integers of the intents